# RabbitMQ: Move expired messages to own dlq?

Tags: rabbitmq

We are sending amqp messages to rabbitMQ and are setting the `message-ttl` property.
If messages got expired, they are moved to the defined DLQ.

Is it possible to have expired messages moved to a seperate DLQ so that they do not interfere with other messages moved to DLQ because of more serious reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

You need to set a Dead Letter Exchange on your queue, and configure the message routing key to change when the messages get expired. Use the x-dead-letter-routing-key arg for this.

Then bind a new queue to your DLX with the dead letter routing key you just defined.

Expired messages will then be sent by RabbitMQ to the DLX, which will route them to the queue you have explicitly defined only for expired messages.

More about this here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html.

Comment: I understand. But how do I change the `x-dead-letter-routing-key` for expired messages?

Comment: any idea how to do the rerouting?